# windows server core 2012 BPA does not complete error

Tags: windows-server-2012

When attempting to run a BPA scan on a remote server core 2012 installation, I'm getting the error "There has been a Best Practice Analyzer error for Model Id 'Microsoft/Windows/WebServer'. The Result file has not yet been generated, Please perform the scan first and try again.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028818 suggests to set script execution policies to certain settings.

> Edit Group Policy/ Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell
>
> Turn on Script Execution

It tried to enable this and it removed the error, only to replace it with KeyNotFoundException